# Swift: Unable to assign function return value to UILabel

Tags: variables, uilabel

I have a situation where a string returned from a function call is being assigned to a `UILabel` text. However, the `UILabel` is carrying an empty value. If I were to assign a static string viz. "this is testing" to the `UILabel` directly it works. Within the function, I can print the return value

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import UIKit
class checkLocation{
    var items = [addedItems]()

    func getLocationOfItem(textFieldText: (String)) -> String{
            let itemLet = addedItems()
            var location = ""
                   Database.database().reference().child("item").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                       if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                           //itemLet.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                           itemLet.itemName = dictionary["itemName"] as? String
                           itemLet.itemLocation = dictionary["itemLocation"] as? String
                           itemLet.itemImageUrl = dictionary["itemImageUrl"] as? String
                           itemLet.itemTS = dictionary["itemTS"] as? String
                           itemLet.id = dictionary["id"] as? String


                         if(textFieldText == itemLet.itemName){
                            location = itemLet.itemLocation!
                            print(location)

                        }
                       }

                   }, withCancel: nil)

        return location
        }

}
```

Calling program

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class checkLocationViewController: ViewController {


            @IBOutlet weak var itemNameInLctn: UITextField!
            @IBOutlet weak var itemLocationLbl: UILabel!


             var items = [addedItems]()

             var strLocation = "";

               override func viewDidLoad() {
                   super.viewDidLoad()
                   refItems = Database.database().reference().child("item")                   
               }


               @IBAction func getLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {                

                self.strLocation = checkLocation().getLocationOfItem(textFieldText: itemNameInLctn.text!)

                itemLocationLbl.text = strLocation

                //itemLocationLbl.text = strLocation

                    //print(itemNameInLctn.text)


               }

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The `func getLocationOfItem(textFieldText: (String)) -> String` is correctly returning `location` that has the initial value of "“.

The issue that you are facing is that, you are calling an an async task from firebase within a sync function call.

You can refactor the method call to return you the required string asynchronously be making the following changes:

```
func getLocationOfItem(textFieldText: String, completion: @escaping (_ itemLocation: String?) -> Void){
    let itemLet = addedItems()
    Database.database().reference().child("item").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return completion(nil)
        }

        itemLet.itemName = dictionary["itemName"] as? String
        itemLet.itemLocation = dictionary["itemLocation"] as? String
        itemLet.itemImageUrl = dictionary["itemImageUrl"] as? String
        itemLet.itemTS = dictionary["itemTS"] as? String
        itemLet.id = dictionary["id"] as? String

        if(textFieldText == itemLet.itemName){
            completion(itemLet.itemLocation)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}

/// Usage

@IBAction func getLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let itemNameInLocation = itemNameInLctn.text else { return }

    getLocationOfItem(textFieldText: itemNameInLocation) { [weak self] (itemLocation) in
        self?.strLocation = itemLocation
        self?.itemLocationLbl.text = itemLocation
    }
}
```

Note:

Please be advised that the completion handler will be called every time that a value is added under the `item` path in your firebase database. 
I would highly recommend refactoring further in this case to use the `observeSingleEvent`that firebase provides.

Please see link below for documentation about said method:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once

If this was your intention then its the best choice.